# UILocalNotification open app automatically

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

Is it possible to implement UILocalNotification so that the app will be automatically opened when the notification is fired?

Comment: I think It's imposibble, you can only open app when you tap to notification alert or in notification center

Comment: Think about this: If anyone makes an app which fires a lot of notification and tries to spam, what will you do ? Do you think apple will allow such a behaviour ? So the simple answer is no, you can't do this. User interaction is needed for opening an app.

Comment: When you firing UILocalNotification in foreground condition local notification receive method also calling so you need to manage this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** NO!

**Long answer:** NO, because user Interaction is needed to open the app. If it wouldn't be needed, anybody would have spammed and this behaviour would have become a great issue to apple...